# Isolating for x in $\log_x(3\sqrt{x}) = k$

Tags: logarithms

I'm having trouble isolating for $x$ in $\log_x(3\sqrt{x}) = k$

I've tried various things. Here is what I ended up with:

$x^{k - \frac{1}{2}} = 3$

I don't know how to proceed. I keep getting stuck. Can anyone help?

Comment: You’re only a step away, raise both sides to the reciprocal of $k-\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: You have done your best.  It seems correct and I do not know how else you could simplify. x seems to be the function for some value of k

Comment: $$\log_x(3\sqrt x)=k\implies x^k=3x^{1/2}\implies x^{k-1/2}=3\implies x=3^{1/(k-1/2)}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have written the power as its definition, ie $x^{k-\frac12}=e^{(k-\frac12)\ln(x)}$ and then take the neperian log on both sides, and get $(k-\frac12) \ln(x)=\ln(3)$. Once you're here, it's quite easy to isolate $x$...

But every logarithm seems to work, so it's up to you !

Answer (score 1):

May be

$(k-\frac{1}{2})logx = log3$

and $x = 10^{\left(\dfrac{log(3)}{k-\frac{1}{2}}\right)}$

Comment: In your answer, you're using base 10 logarithm. Here, it's a base $x$ logarithm...

Comment: @ThomasPrévost He is continuing from the last step , and is taking log base 10 on either side

Comment: The expression stands correct by definition

Comment: @RahulRamachandran my bad, I didn't see you took the log at the begining... So it's correct, I apologize

Comment: @ThomasPrévost, No worries!!